# How to import data from a sheet where sheetname is dependent on a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to make a Google Sheet for some purpose which shall have details of various movies.
Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10-4BWaK-zmTxmqr2ov7AvjQW-wAFR8NKXkICuCK1dTY/edit?usp=sharing

Now I wish to count the number of movies per year where sheet name is dependent on cell value.
For example, in Sheet: `"Data"` I wish that `B2` shows the count of movies in Sheet named `'2019'` but I don't want it to be written as `'=COUNTA('2019'!A:A)`. Instead I wish that the sheet name automatically gets picked up from cell `A2`. So if I change the year in `A2`, the Count in `B2` should change automatically.

I tried using `INDIRECT` and `MATCH` function as `=COUNTA(INDIRECT(A2,false))` and `=MATCH(A2,INDIRECT(A2),1)` but I think I made some errors.

Also in the same way I wish to count in `C2` but with a condition: `to count only those cells from G column where value is watched`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B2 try

```
=sumproduct(INDIRECT(A2&"!A3:A")<>"")
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Also I had another query which I forgot to mention earlier. Just added at the  of the question, If you can help?

Comment: The value 'watched' is not present in the drop down. I assume you meat 'Yes' ? If so, try: =SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT(A2&"!G3:G557")="Yes")

Comment: Ya that's what I want. some fellow editor might have replaced it as yes instead of watched. thanks

Comment: In that case, change "Yes" to "Watched" or simply refer to the value in C1: =SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT(A2&"!G3:G557")=$C$1)